# send NSData to another process and not just pointer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, serialization, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send NSString via Game Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621898/send-nsstring-via-game-center)

i have been working on this for two days now and not been getting anywhere, i was hoping someone could shed some light on the problem.

1) i have an NSMUtableArray
2) each element within the array is serialised through [encoder encodeObject: myArray]; and the result is returned and assigned to a struct "MessageMove"  called "cards" (of type NSData *)
MessageMove message;

....

```
typedef struct
{
    Message message;
    NSData  *cards;
} MessageMove;
```

3) Now that the cards have been converted to type NSData i now want to do the same for the struct itself, i call

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)];

4) Finally i send the data to the other player as follows

```
BOOL success = [[GCHelper sharedInstance].match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error];
```

the trouble lies with the receiving end not getting any of the Cards data at all (MessageMove->cards). This is probably because the NSData * is not being sent remotely but rather only the pointer to it.

Does anyone know how i can send the actual data? I have been scratching my head all day at this problem and don't know how i can overcome it

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `MessageMove` an Objective-C class that conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol.  Then serialise it to an `NSData` object, and deserialise it on the other end.  For more details, see [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621898/send-nsstring-via-game-center/9622017#9622017).